# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request - PHP Error

Tags: php, http-post

SOLUTION: I had malformed my JSON data for the payload body.  The `"ttl" => 30` was in the incorrect array() method.  This probably won't help anyone in the future, moving the ttl key/value pair made this work correctly as seen below.

```
$data = array( 
    "statement" => array( 
        "actor" => array(
            "mbox" => "mailto:test@example.com"
        ),
    ),
    "ttl" => 30
);
```

I have checked numerous other StackOverflow questions and cannot find a solution that works.  I should note that I am testing this using a local XAMPP server running on port 8080.  Not sure if that matters.  I have been able to get this working using Postman, but translating it to PHP has been problematic.  Am I missing something?  I am not all that familiar with PHP, but need this for work.

EDIT: Some more information about what the API is expecting.  It's a fairly simple API that requires a JSON body, a Basic Authorization header, and a Content-Type: application/json.

Here is the JSON body I am using in Postman. This is a direct copy/paste from Postman, which is successfully communicating with the API:

```
{
    "statement": {
        "actor": {
            "mbox": "mailto:test@example.com"
        }
    },
    "ttl": 30
}
```

Is there a syntax error in my below PHP code for this?  Again, I am learning PHP on the fly so I'm unsure if I am properly constructing a JSON payload using the `array()` method in PHP.

My code below has the `$https_user`,`$https_password`, and `$url` domain changed for obvious security reasons.  In my actual PHP code, I have the same credentials and domain used in Postman.

The `$randomSessionID` serves no real purpose other than an identification number for future requests.  Has no affect on the API response failing or succeeding.

```
<?php
$https_user = 'username';
$https_password = 'password';
$randomSessionID = floor((mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax()) * 10000000);

$url = 'https://www.example.com/session/' . $randomSessionID . '/launch';

$json = json_encode(array( 
    "statement" => array( 
        "actor" => array(
            "mbox" => "mailto:test@example.com"
        ),"ttl" => 30 
    )
));

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n'.
        "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$https_user:$https_password")."\r\n",
        'content' => $json
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

?>
```

Comment: Whatever you are sending to has complained about a bad request. Since you haven't given any details about what that is, or what the request format should be, it's difficult to see how we can help.

Comment: It means that whatever URL you are sending to is denying access due to  malformed data/syntax  during `POST`  This can be because the data you are sending is invalid.  It can also be because the page `METHOD` only allows `GET` or `PUT`  --  There are really tons of reasons you can get a 400 error, including misconfigured "receiving" page.

Comment: I have updated my original post with more information about the requirements for the API.  Would appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: I had malformed my JSON data for the payload body.  The `"ttl" => 30` was in the incorrect array() method.  This probably won't help anyone in the future, but moving the ttl key/value pair made this work correctly as seen below.

```
$data = array( 
    "statement" => array( 
        "actor" => array(
            "mbox" => "mailto:test@example.com"
        ),
    ),
    "ttl" => 30
);
```